# Django forms on base template

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

The website I'm building has a login form as part of the base.html template that all the other templates extend; as a result of this I need to somehow handle login/logout logic on every single page.

Currently each page is loaded in a separate view so what is the best and most DRY way of implementing this? all the tutorials I'm reading have the login page separated.

Edit:

My original method was making the forms action always load the index and the pretty much worked however I was annoyed by the fact that I couldn't redirect the user back to wherever they were before they logged in.

afterwards I decided to redesign the form as a Django ModelForm so that I could raise validation errors which I didn't manage to do before but now the template only has the ModelForm object when it is rendered through the index view so the input boxes aren't even rendered on other pages..

Comment: so what are you saying is that you are currently implemening the form logic in each view instead of doing it once?

Comment: yes, and I may have many more views in the future, it just seems ridicoulus

Answer (score 2):

You can put a check around your login form code in your template.

You can put the login template in a `base_login.html` and extend it on every page.

A sample base template code:

```
{% if not user.is_authenticated %}
    <form action="{% url my_login_url %}" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input id="username_field" name="username" type="text" />
        <input id="password_field" name="password" type="password" />
        <button type="submit">Login</button>
    </form>
```

This login form will be displayed only if the user is not authenticated.

Then write a view for `login` page and a `LoginForm` to handle the login process.

**views.py**

```
class LoginView(FormView):

    ...
    your login and redirection logic here
    ...
```

**forms.py**

```
class LoginForm(forms.Form):

    username = ..
    password = ..

    ...
    your form validations and other logic
    ...
```

So, be it any page, login form will be displayed only if user has not loggedin and all these login requests will go to your `LoginView` only.
You don't need to worry about handling the login logic in each view.

Comment: To extend on this, you can (and should, per the DRY principle) place this code in a `base_login.html` file that resides in a separate directory from your apps and that you use the [extends](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/templates/#template-inheritance) tag to include within each template (I would recommend doing this for any other repeated code as well). Then, in your `settings.py`, simply add the directory to the `TEMPLATES`'s `DIRS` option [(see this link for info)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/templates/)

Comment: Yes we can do that. That would be a DRYer approach. Added it to the ans.

Comment: I think I might be confused about the concept of a view and a url

Comment: URL is a normal url or the path of a page.  When a visitor’s browser asks for a URL, Django matches the request against its `urls.py` files. If a match is found, Django moves on to the view that’s associated with that URL. The view generally handles all the database manipulation. It grabs data and passes it on. A template (specified in the view) then displays that data. http://www.webmonkey.com/2010/02/use_url_patterns_and_views_in_django/

Comment: Isn't a view supposed to represent a page though? and a url a link to that page? Why would I have a separate url and view for logging in when I'm actually logging in from existing urls and views (the pages of the website)

Also, how would I raise errors like wrong username or password next to the form if it changes url in order to log in

Comment: Here, login view will be a `FormView`. It will have a url but it will redirect to the page you define if login was successful. If it failed, then errors would be shown on that page itself. You can use `{{form.errors}}` in your login template to display the errors if any on submitting the form.

Answer (score 1):

The best option is to create a HEADER.HTML template and include that in your base.html with the help of includes.
This will be a better option then creating or displayin a form in base.html, you can also do the same for footer.

Comment: how is this better than having a skeleton base.html with a header and footer?